# .NET MAUI BLAZOR SOFT KEYBOARD BUG

Tags: .net, windows, tablet, maui-blazor

I have .Net Maui Hybrid blazor application. whenever I click an input field like textbox, numberbox and etc. It worked fine, But when I plug a scanner/keyboard on my windows tablet and started scanning/typing it will hide the whole keyboard and cannot be triggered anymore unless I will click outside the application and click to the input field again.

I want to be able to show the soft keyboard specially after scanning a barcode.

Comment: Question title - in ALL CAPS - people ignore these questions as they think you are SHOUTING at them.